# Is there a way to tag a job in lsf when you create it, something you can search on later on?

Tags: lsf

Is there a way to tag a job in lsf with a user specified value... something I can search for later?

Let's say I create a job and I want to find it among all the other jobs I might have running.  I don't know it's job_id, I don't know it's state, etc... .  But I do know that when I created it, I tagged it with a value that I was hoping I could search on.  So in theory...
lsf bsub -q xyz -P abc -tag daves_job_mon_aug_31

Answer (score 0):

You can name a job with `-J`:

```
bsub -q xyz -P abc -J daves_job_mon_aug_31 ...
```

Which will show up in `bjobs` output under the `JOB_NAME` column.  If the name is too long it'll get truncated in the ouput but you can override that behavior using `bjobs -w` to show wide output.